# iOS: How to remove overlay from it's subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiview

I have button that makes overlay with label and X button on it:

```
- (IBAction)taptaxi:(id)sender {
    UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:.7];
    UILabel *waiting = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 210, 250, 30)] autorelease];
    waiting.text = @"Waiting for cab response...";
    waiting.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    waiting.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   
    waiting.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    UIButton *stoprequest = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 219, 13, 13)];
    UIImage *srbackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"iks.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [stoprequest setBackgroundImage:srbackground forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [stoprequest addTarget: self action: @selector(stopRequestMethod:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view.window addSubview:overlay];
    [overlay addSubview:waiting];
    [overlay addSubview:stoprequest];


}

- (void)stopRequestMethod: (id)sender
{
}
```

**Question is**, how to hide/remove overlay with label and button when I tap on X butoon (stopRequestMethod)?

Comment: Release overlay after you added it as subview. You may consider to set the hidden property of your overlay instead of calling removeFromSuperview to skip the process of initializing the overlay over and over again when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your  overlay a tag:

```
overlay.tag = 42;
```

Then, in your method that gets called when the X button is pressed:

```
UIView *overlay = [self.view.window viewWithTag:42];
[overlay removeFromSuperview];
```